# MySQL row empty

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query, that runs on user input.

How would I write an IF statement to see if a row is set?

I have tried:

```
if (!isset($row['example']) === true) {
//row not set
}
```

and:

```
if (empty($row['example'])) {
//row not set
}
```

Thanks!

***Edit: The first IF statement I tried actually did work. Sorry for any trouble I caused.

Comment: If I understand you correctly: you run the query and see if any rows were returned, usually by testing the length of the returned array. It would help if we saw a more complete sample of your code, though.

Comment: Just a side note: You don't need to do `(!isset($row['example']) === true)`, it can be written as `(!isset($row['example']))` because `isset()` returns a boolean value. So writing `!isset($var)` will check if `isset()` returns false.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'll remember that

Comment: @user2180108 no problem, can you share more of your code with us?

Comment: I have a user input, which accesses a database. If the input matches something in the database, it checks which type the command was that was entered, which is $row['type']. Then it does different things depending on the value of $row['type']. if ($row['type'] == 1) {}; if ($row['type'] == 2) {}; etc. Then, at the end, I want to see if the command matched the database at all, by seeing if $row['type'] is set. The problem being, that if statement doesn't work.

Comment: False alarm, I had a badly placed IF statement. Everything works now. thanks for the help!

Comment: @user2180108 not a problem, feel free to post your solution as an answer and accept it, or close the question. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

Simple check would be

```
if(isset($row['example']))
```

or better check you have any records returned from sql using

```
mysql_num_rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way ever:

```
if ((isset($row) === true) !== false) {
    if(!empty($row) === true){
       echo "row is good";
    }
}
```

Comment: you're gonna confuse the guy